# Unable to connect after setting up tunnel to lightsail instance PHPMyAdmin

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, phpmyadmin, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

After setting up my lightsail instance I tried to follow the instructions at [bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/get-started/access-phpmyadmin/)
I  used the `ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -i file.pem bitnami@ip` to connect.

I get the expected result with nothing returned in the terminal. Now when I try to visit 127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin I get an error from FF saying unable to connect. I have also tried switching the port to 433 incase that was the issue and visited 127.0.0.1:8443/phpmyadmin and still no luck.

another post suggested I add a slash at the end, that didnt work either. I have turned of my local apache server on my ubuntu machine as I felt that would help yet no show.

I have also ensured I didnt accidentally close the terminal

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi, could you please let us know the Bitnami solution you are using? We would like to confirm that phpMyAdmin is included in that solution. Apart from that, you can also confirm that by running this command from the instance's command line `curl -LI localhost/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be that the key file didnt have the right permissions.Once I corrected the permissions as specified in the docs I was able to connect but so far have got the https connection to work and just use http which is less than ideal